# syntax for tar + gunzip included

Tags: linux, shell, tar, gzip, split

I wanted to `tar` some directory with `gzip` included. Please let me know what is the syntax for it. Following are also to be considered.

1) It would be helpful if the `tar.gz` is getting split after 2G is completed with one tar file.( say: `tar.gzaa` becomes 2G, then it should continue to create `tar.gzab`)

2) syntax for appending the log info into a log file

3) to exclude some type of files with particular extension ( say my source directory which is going to be tar is having some child dir with `.log` files and i need to exclude those to be get tarred.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi. What have you tried so far?

Comment: The answer below satisfies your question?
If yes, please accept it. If not, what else do you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
tar --exclude='*.EXTENSION' -czvf - DIRECTORY/ 2> LOG_FILE.log | split --verbose --bytes=2048MB - FILE.tar.gz. >> LOG_FILE.log
```

---

Let's test. Assuming we have a directory named `directory` with this files:

```
eduardo@Notebook:~/testtar$ ll -h directory/
total 570M
drwxr-xr-x 2 eduardo eduardo 4,0K mar  6 23:25 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 eduardo eduardo 4,0K mar  6 23:28 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 eduardo eduardo    0 mar  6 23:16 file.any
-rw-r--r-- 1 eduardo eduardo 570M mar  6 23:24 hugefile.dd
-rw-r--r-- 1 eduardo eduardo    0 mar  6 23:15 image.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 eduardo eduardo    0 mar  6 23:16 log.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 eduardo eduardo    0 mar  6 23:14 text.txt
```

**Tar command:**

```
tar --exclude='*.log' -czvf - directory/ 2> splitted_tar.log | split --verbose --bytes=50MB - splitted_tar_file.tar.gz. >> splitted_tar.log
```

**Output files:**

```
eduardo@Notebook:~/testtar$ ll -h
total 299M
drwxr-xr-x  3 eduardo eduardo 4,0K mar  6 23:53 ./
drwxr-xr-x 41 eduardo eduardo 4,0K mar  6 23:16 ../
drwxr-xr-x  2 eduardo eduardo 4,0K mar  6 23:25 directory/
-rw-r--r--  1 eduardo eduardo  48M mar  6 23:52 splitted_tar_file.tar.gz.aa
-rw-r--r--  1 eduardo eduardo  48M mar  6 23:53 splitted_tar_file.tar.gz.ab
-rw-r--r--  1 eduardo eduardo  48M mar  6 23:53 splitted_tar_file.tar.gz.ac
-rw-r--r--  1 eduardo eduardo  48M mar  6 23:53 splitted_tar_file.tar.gz.ad
-rw-r--r--  1 eduardo eduardo  48M mar  6 23:53 splitted_tar_file.tar.gz.ae
-rw-r--r--  1 eduardo eduardo  48M mar  6 23:53 splitted_tar_file.tar.gz.af
-rw-r--r--  1 eduardo eduardo  13M mar  6 23:53 splitted_tar_file.tar.gz.ag
-rw-r--r--  1 eduardo eduardo  399 mar  6 23:53 splitted_tar.log
```

**Log file:**

```
eduardo@Notebook:~/testtar$ cat splitted_tar.log 
directory/
directory/text.txt
directory/hugefile.dd
directory/file.any
directory/image.jpg
creating file 'splitted_tar_file.tar.gz.aa'
creating file 'splitted_tar_file.tar.gz.ab'
creating file 'splitted_tar_file.tar.gz.ac'
creating file 'splitted_tar_file.tar.gz.ad'
creating file 'splitted_tar_file.tar.gz.ae'
creating file 'splitted_tar_file.tar.gz.af'
creating file 'splitted_tar_file.tar.gz.ag'
```

**Notes:**

- The file `log.log` is not include in the final `.tar.gz` file due the
  parameter `--exclude` (make sure to put it before the source and
  destination items)
- Tar verbose output goes to STDERR, this is why I used `2> LOG_FILE.log`
- Split verbose output goes to STDOUT, I just appended it with `>> LOG_FILE.log`
- To "restore" your directory (join, gunzip and untar), you can use:

  ```
   cat splitted_tar_file.tar.gz.a? | tar -xzvf -
  ```